# Unable to use Itext7 and other 3rd party library after updating to Android Studio Chipmunk

Tags: android-studio, itext7

I just update my Android Studio to Chipmunk 2021.2.1 and my itext code dont work anymore. Im using itext7-core:7.2.2.

[image]

How do i fix this?

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I face the same problem in other libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with another library.

In my case, I was managing the library locally and importing it into my project as a jar file.

Specifying the path to the jar file directly solved the problem.
In my case, the problem was solved by adding the following notation to the app-level build.gradle.

> ```
> // MyLibrary
> implementation project(':MyLibrary')
> implementation files("... /MyLibrary/library.jar") // added
> ```

Comment: I already report this bug to android studio so it will probably get fixed in future, so using local library is an alternative to fix this.
There is a video on youtube if you still dont understand how to add jar files locally